# Windows 10 ＋ AnacondaでCUDAを利用可能にするには？

Tags: python, 機械学習, windows-10, gpu, cuda

Teratailで回答を得られなかったので、こちらに投稿しています。

BigSleepというAI画像生成のパッケージが動かしたいと思っています。
Windows 10 （RTX2060Super搭載）にAnaconda3.9最新版をインストールし、コマンドプロンプトから以下のようにインストールを試みましたが失敗しました。

```
$ conda create -n painter
$ conda activate painter
$ conda install python==3.6.10
$ conda install  cudnn=7.6.5=cuda10.0_0
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
$ pip install big-sleep
$ dream "a pyramid made of ice"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\Scripts\dream.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\site-packages\big_sleep\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from big_sleep.big_sleep import BigSleep, Imagine
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\site-packages\big_sleep\big_sleep.py", line 26, in <module>
    assert torch.cuda.is_available(), 'CUDA must be available in order to use Big Sleep'
AssertionError: CUDA must be available in order to use Big Sleep
```

参考サイト:
[UbuntuにAnacondaで構築するTensorFlow-GPU環境構築 〜CUDA、cuDNNインストール編〜](https://qiita.com/captain-sadami/items/c9be816856c57ef0ae52)
[AI画像生成を行うBig Sleep（CLIP+BigGAN）のインストール](https://self-development.info/ai%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86big-sleep%EF%BC%88clipbiggan%EF%BC%89%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/)

エラーメッセージで検索するとpytorchをインストールせよという情報があったので試しましたが駄目でした。

```
$ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
$ dream "a pyramid made of ice"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\Scripts\dream.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\site-packages\big_sleep\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from big_sleep.big_sleep import BigSleep, Imagine
  File "C:\Users\hoge\anaconda3\envs\painter\lib\site-packages\big_sleep\big_sleep.py", line 26, in <module>
    assert torch.cuda.is_available(), 'CUDA must be available in order to use Big Sleep'
AssertionError: CUDA must be available in order to use Big Sleep
```

他にも、Anacondaを再インストールしてやり直したり、conda経由ではなくNVIDIAのサイトからドライバーをインストールしたりしましたが駄目でした。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
すべて一からやり直したらうまくいきました。

Answer (score 0):

PyPIからのインストールで-c pytorchのところを-c torchではできませんか？

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。つい先程、自己解決しました。